# Haar training - where to obtain eyeglasses images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to train a new haar-cascade for glasses as I'm not satisfied with the results I'm getting from the cascade that is included in OpenCV.

My main problem is that I'm not sure where to get eyeglasses images. I can manually search and download, but that's not practical for the amount of images I really need. I'm specifically looking for images of people wearing eyeglasses.

As this forum contain many experienced computer vision experts, I hope someone here can guide as to how to obtain images for training.

I'll also be happy to hear other approaches for detecting eyeglasses (on people).

Thanks in advance,

Gil

Comment: One suggestion if you cannot find the images of people in eyeglasses you need, is to snap them yourself, and perhaps share it with others if you like(: I did them last time for number of fingers held up detection. Snapped lots of pictures with the fingers, which took close to 3 days. That's cause I can't find those I need online.

Comment: Check out this [dataset](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html) contains faces with glasses. But still, you need to manually label them.

Comment: Thanks for both answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want images, it looks like @herhuyongtao pointed you to a good place. Then you can follow opencv's [tutorial on training](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html).

Another option is to see what others have trained:
There's a trained data set found [here](http://www.myexperiment.org/files/422.html) that might be of use, which states simply that it is "better". I'm assuming that it's supposed to be better than opencv.

I didn't immediately see any other places for trained or labeled data.